# What contract is between URL bar address and page/file/action in JSF web app?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I see that address is not changed after going to second page (file) through bean action.

Comment: The effect you're seeing is coming from [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) which JSF uses to display the result view of a form submit. This should explain a lot if you know/understand the basic Servlet API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bozho is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763421/what-contract-is-between-url-bar-address-and-page-file-action-in-jsf-web-app/5763483#5763483).

If you want to update the URL, the default mechanism is to use an *outcome* like `/foo/bar?faces-redirect=true` to redirect after the POST. There is also a `<redirect/>` instruction if you're using *faces-config.xml* `navigation-rule`s. Details can be found in section *7.4.2 Default NavigationHandler Algorithm* of the [JSF 2 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314).

Answer (score 2):

jsf actions happen by submitting the form to the same URL. JSF then decides, based on request parameters, which action to invoke. After that navigation rules are resolved in order to show the user the correct page. But navigation rules are by default using forward (server-side redirect), and so the client does not see a change in the url.